# Generating button and adding method with a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to practice with constructor functions.
I wrote a function which creates buttons at runtime and add some methods to these buttons.

```
$(function () {

    $('#generateNew').on('click', function () {
        new VerySpecialButton();
    })


    var globalNumberCounter = 0,
        $holder = $('#buttonHolder');

    function VerySpecialButton() {

        thisButton = this;

        this.number = globalNumberCounter++;

        this.specialEvent = function () {
            alert(thisButton.number)
        }

        this.$button = $('<button>')
            .text('Button[' + thisButton.number + ']')
            .on('click', thisButton.specialEvent)
            .appendTo($holder)
    }

})
```

When clicking any button I want this button to alert its number. But every button alerts last created buttons number.

You will understand clearly what I mean if you check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bgWSf/).

Could someone help me to find where I am wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't set `thisButton` as global variable:

[SEE jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgWSf/3/)

```
var thisButton = this;
```